# Running Windows 10 insdie Windows 10 Virtual machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I create tutorial and video courses. There are times that I want to start off from scratch in a video that I am making to show how to install a particular piece of software.

But as I am working on my development PC that would mean Uninstalling and reinstalling and reconfiguring the software. Something that I do not want.

I currently have Windows 10 as my primary OS.

How can I run a new instance of the same Windows 10 inside it?

I have no Idea where to start so do point me in the right direction if you are unable to give a detailed answer.

Thanks

Comment: "How can I run a new instance of the same Windows 10 inside it?" - Use the hypervisor of your choice and install Windows on the virtual machine

Comment: TechNet tutorial for setting Hyper-V can be found here: [Step-By-Step: Enabling Hyper-V for use on Windows 10](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/) and setting up the virtual hard drive (VHD) and Windows 10 image can be found here: [Create a Virtual Machine with Hyper-V Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/create-virtual-machine). Is this the sort of information you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V would be my first choice. But, it is only available on Windows 10 Pro or higher. If you are running Home you are not able to add the Hyper-V role. If you are using Home edition you will have to install another hypervisor like VirtualBox (my second choice).

Once you setup the hypervisor, create a new virtual machine with sufficient storage space to install and operate another copy of Windows. "Plug in" a Windows 10 installation .ISO to setup Windows. Use the hypervisor's "snapshot" feature to take snapshots of the OS BEFORE you make any significant changes, or along the way. This way you can revert back instantly to any previous state of the OS. This is great for making tutorials, because you can install all the software and take your screenshots and just revert back to a clean OS in seconds.

How to setup Hyper-V on Windows 10 (Additional links to the left give you more information about creating and managing virtual machines): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

Here's a quick Tutorial on setting up Windows 10 on VirtualBox (Just make sure to use a general release copy of Windows 10 and not the insider preview): https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/04/01/step-by-step-installing-windows-10-on-oracle-virtualbox/

Download the latest Windows 10 installer .ISO. This is needed to install Windows on your virtual machine: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10